# Are the following claims for converging infinite complex series true by the same arguments for complex sequences?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$ be two converging complex series. It is known that

1.) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha a_n + \beta b_n = \left(\alpha\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\right) + \left(\beta\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\right)$,

2.) $\overline{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{a}_n$,

3.) $\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm{Re}(a_n), \mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm{Im}(a_n)$.

If the same results for complex sequences are thought to be known, aren't the claims 1-3 true from the get-go, since the sequences of partial sums are complex sequences as well. By "same" results I mean that suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = L_1, \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = L_2$, $L_1, L_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ for complex sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty, \{b_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$. Then,

i.) $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha a_n + \beta b_n = \left(\alpha\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right) + \left(\beta\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\right)$,

ii.) $\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\overline{a}_n$,

iii.) $\mathrm{Re}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{Re}(a_n), \mathrm{Im}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{Im}(a_n)$.

I am asking this since essentially all complex analysis books show the same arguments for both series and sequences, and I'm not sure is it because the proof technique and the sequence nature of the infinite series is wanted to emphasize, or because the claims do not automatically follow.

Comment: Yes, they do follow from the similar statements for sequences.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I would accept this answer if I could. Should I close this thread?

Comment: I cannot post my comment as an answer since we have a policy against answers of the type “Yes, you are right”. But my guess is that there is no problem if you just do nothing.